# Function Return Type: Pointer, Reference or something else?

Tags: c++, c++98

Let us assume I always need the direkt return type of the function to be of a errorcode (success of calculation or failure) , then I will return some arguments as parameters. Is it better to define them as reference (and create them before empty) or better to return pointer?

Edit: I should be more precise: The errorcode is obligatory because I have to stick to the coding guidline given.

Possibility A:

```
ErrorCode func( some_parameters ... , ReturnType & result)
...
ReturnType result; // empty constructor, probably not good practice
func( some_parameters ..., result)
```

Possibility B:

```
ErrorCode func( some_parameters ... , ReturnType * result){
    ...
    result =  new ReturnType(...)
    ...
}
...
ReturnType * result; // void pointer
func( some_parameters ..., result)
...
delete result; // this is needed if I do not use a smart pointer
```

Even better: Maybe you have a more appropriate solution?

**Edit: Please indicate which standard you are using, since unfortunatelly (guidelines) I have to stick to C++98.**

Comment: If you always create ReturnType, I would personally use version (A). Other alternatives would be to return an std::optional or std::unique_ptr.

Comment: C99 is not a C++ standard. Do you mean C++98?

Comment: C89 and C99 (and C11) are C standards. C++98, C++11, C++14 are C++ standards. You have tagged with both C++ and a C standard. The link you give is to a page entitled "ANSI_C".

Comment: Oh, I see my flaw, I will correct it.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following (and in general do)

1.) throw an exception instead of returning error codes

if this is not possible (for any reason)

2.) return the pointer directly (either raw or std::unique_ptr) and return nullptr for failure

if return type has to be bool or not all objects returned are (pointers / heap allocated)

3.) return your error code (bool or enum class) and accept a reference parameter for all objects that are to be initialized (must have objects so to speak) and pointers to objects that may be optionally created / initialized

if the object cannot be created in advance to the call (e.g. because it is not default constructible)

4.) pass a reference to a pointer (raw or std::unique_ptr) or a pointer to a pointer, which will then be filled by the function

std::optional (or similar) may be an option if you only have a true/false return code.

I don't like returning std::pair or std::tuple because it can make your code look quite annoying if you have to start using .first/.second or std::get<>() to access your different return types. Using std::tie() can reduce this a little bit, but it is not (yet) very comfortable to use and prevents the use of const.

Examples:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> func1() { /* ... */ throw MyException("..."); }

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> func2() { /* ... */ }

ErrorCode func3(MyClass& obj, std::string* info = nullptr) { /* ... */ }

ErrorCode func4(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& obj) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
     try 
     {
          auto myObj1 = func1();
          // use ...
     }
     catch(const MyException& e)
     {
          // handle error ...
     }

     if(auto myObj2 = func2())
     {
          // use ...
     }

     MyClass myObj3;
     std::string info;
     ErrorCode error = func3(myObj3, &info);
     if(error == ErrorCode::NoError)
     {
          // use ...
     }

     std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myObj4;
     ErrorCode error = func4(myObj4);
     if(error == ErrorCode::NoError)
     {
          // use ...
     }
 }
```

Edit: And in general it is advisable to keep your API consistent, so if you already have a medium or large codebase, which makes use of one or the other strategy you should stick to that (if you do not have good reasons not to).

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical example for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). Sadly it isn't available yet, so you want to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

This is assuming that the result is always either "success with result" or "fail without result". If your result code is more complicated you can return
`std::pair<ResultCode, std::optional<ReturnType>>`.

Comment: or `std::experimental::optional`

Answer (score 2):

It would be good style to to use the return value for all return information. For example:

```
std::tuple<bool, ReturnType> func(input_args....)
```

Alternatively, the return type could be `std::optional` (or its precursor) if the status code is boolean, with an empty `optional` indicating that the function failed.

However, if the calculation is supposed to normally succeed, and only fail in rare circumstances, it would be better style to just return `ReturnType`, and throw an exception to indicate failure.

Code is much easier to read when it doesn't have error-checking on every single return value; but to be robust code those errors do need to be checked somewhere or other. Exceptions let you handle a range of exceptional conditions in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's applicable in your situation but if you have only two state return type then maybe just return pointer from your function and then test if it is nullptr?

Comment: This would make memory management more complicated, as you would need to manually allocate memory for the return value (and have the caller manually free it)